# Script task failed to generate dynamic Excel workbook

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I want to load sql query(Number of column change every time)data in Excel workbook that create column header dynamically.

First i have create four variable

[image]

Table **Customer_NA** have some entries

[image]

And create Ado.net connection and configure server-name and database name

[image]

Drag Script task and and assign all 4 variable in ReadOnlyVariable.

[image]

Edit Script task and write code to generate excel sheet column dynamically

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try
        {
            //Declare Variables
            string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString();
            string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
            string SheetName = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
            ExcelFileName = ExcelFileName + "_" + datetime;

            OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();

            //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
            string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;" + "Data Source=" + FolderPath + ExcelFileName
                + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

            //drop Excel file if exists
            File.Delete(FolderPath + "\\" + ExcelFileName + ".xlsx");

            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["Ado_Conn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

            //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
            // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
            string queryString =
              "SELECT * from " + TableName;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);


            //Get Header Columns
            string TableColumns = "";

            // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    TableColumns += column + "],[";
                }
            }

            // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
            TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
            TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);
            //MessageBox.Show(TableColumns);


            //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
            Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
            Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                String sqlCommandValue = "";
                foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                {
                    sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                }

                sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into " + SheetName + "(" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',') + ") VALUES(";

                int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    string columnvalues = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                    {
                        int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                        columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i] + "',";

                    }
                    columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                    var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
            Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

            }
        }
    }
```

Same **Ado_Conn** connection name i have write in c# script still facing error
[image]
 after successfully buid script and run package and got error

Please help me out

[image]

**I hope i Explain the scnerio**

Answer (score 1):

[image]
The alert shows a generic error message, therefore it is not possible to pinpoint the cause of the error.

Consider to add this line into a `CATCH` block:

```
Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task Example", exception.Message + "\r" + exception.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
```

Also, perhaps it makes sense, for now, temporarily disable writing logs into a custom log file since this operation by itself can cause errors and they will not be captured by `try..catch..`.

So the edited version will look this way:

```
catch (Exception exception)
        {
           Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task", exception.Message + "\r" + exception.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
        // Create Log File for Errors
        //    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
        //        Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
        //    {
        //        sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        //        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

        //    }
        }
```

The real reason of the exception will be routed to SSIS logs and can be tracked via SSDT output window or native SSIS Catalog logging in case if the package is deployed to a server

Comment: :I have used your catch block code but still giving same error...What is the meaning of this error" exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"..Is there any 32 bit set up problem?

Comment: Exact Error message is--"Error: 0x0 at Script Task, Script Task: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   at ST_2f1b6d2c6495444e9e4901edee0878df.ScriptMain.Main()
Error: 0x1 at Script Task: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Task failed: Script Task"

Comment: you are trying to refer to a non-exist variable in the script, compare and see if all the user variables are checked and properly typed if manually did (case sensitive)

Comment: This is a real error: ***The element cannot be found in a collection**. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables*.  It means that one of the calls to a variable array cannot resolve a variable name

Comment: @AlexanderVolok:How can i resolve this error? ..I have shown each and every thing what i did

Comment: I have copied every thing as tutor suggest in this link :http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/03/how-to-create-excel-file-dynamically.html

Comment: @Ankush, take a look on a declared variable **Folderpath**. The Script Task refers to a **FolderPath**. Take into account that C# is a case sensitive language.